# Textfield Validation using CharacterSet

Tags: ios, swift, nscharacterset

I have written below code to validate text input in textfield.

```
else if (textField == txtField_Password)
    {
        let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@$&*!")
        let charLength = (txtField_Password.text!.count) + (string.count) - range.length

        for i in 0..<string.count
        {
            let c = (string as NSString).character(at: i)
            if (!((charSet as NSCharacterSet).characterIsMember(c)))
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        return (charLength > 20) ? false : true
    }
```

Can anyone help me to convert character(at:) and characterIsMember() part to its swift equivalent in the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the logic just by checking the range of the **inverted** character set. If the string contains only allowed characters the function returns `nil`.

```
else if textField == txtField_Password {
    let charLength = txtField_Password.text!.utf8.count + string.utf8.count - range.length
    let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@$&*!")
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet.inverted) == nil && charLength < 21
}
```

Comment: I implemented your answer and it is working. I just wanted to ask why to use utf8 in string.utf8.count

Comment: A single character can contain more than one byte, counting the utf8 representation of the string makes it more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a simpler way to implement what you want using a regular expression:

```
let currentText = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
let newText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

let pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9@$&*!]{0,20}$"
return newText.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

Comment: Why use of NSString?

Comment: @YashArunJadhav Because `replacingCharacters` with `NSRange` is defined only on `NSString` and using `NSRange` with swift `String` is basically impossible. Note that `newText` is a `String`.

Comment: Can you please try to implement your answer with only swift.

Comment: @YashArunJadhav This is pure Swift. You cannot ignore the fact that `UIKit` was written in Objective-C and uses Objective-C types like `NSRange`.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with something along these lines.  I appreciate this is a bit rough and ready but should work:

```
charSet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@$&*!"

if txtField_Password.text!.count <= 20 {

    for i in 0..<str.count
    {
        let c = Array(str)[i]

        let cString = String(c)

        if charSet.contains(cString) {
            return false
           }
        }

    } else {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Textfield should only accept 20 characters. Can you please edit your answer based on above code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rangeOfCharacter`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       let specialCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@$&*!"


       let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: specialCharacters)

       guard let lengh = textfield.text else {return} 
       if lengh.count >= 20 {
         // text exceeded 20 characters. Do something 
       }     

       if (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) != nil) {
              print("matched")
              return true
          } else { 
              print("not matched")
       }

    return true
 }
```

Comment: I was trying to implement your answer but result of searchText is not used.

Comment: You can safely remove searchText. It should work without that

Comment: Yes it is working but I also want to have check for character length, how can I implement it.

Comment: The length of your textfield?